# Syncing a local database to an online database (Paradox -> SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, synchronization, paradox

What would be the best way to sync a local Paradox database to an online SQL database?

It only needs to be a one way system; I need it to upload a phone logging database into my SQL database.

Currently I have a program that exports the table into a CSV and then uploads it to the sites FTP and then I was going to create a script to import that into the database for me, is there a better way / program to go about achieving this?

Many thanks.

Comment: I think you are on the right track.  What is the export program written in?  Do you have the ability to write a program on a platform that connects to the local Paradox database?

Comment: Hello, the program itself was written to interact with the database on a two way basis. It has several 'modules' including Exporting, FTP, Import, Upload, Download and a few others - It was written in Delphi and interacts with the BDE. 

I did find a program called DBConvert for Excel and MySQL but I am preferably looking for a solution with one program running as opposed to one for export then another for upload and insertion.